# Multiple Variables Reading in read prompt

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am a beginner at shell scripts, and i am trying to create a basic script that creates starter environnements for web projects.

I would like to tell my case loop, to read all arguments passed to read -p 'package name ?' and if one of them equal to case option execute that option. For example, if i write 'package name' npm git, do npm init and git init.

```
read -p 'folder name ?' nom
mkdir /Users/ineszarka/Sites/$nom
cd /Users/ineszarka/Sites/$nom
read -p 'package name ?' opt optt
case $opt OR $optt  in
        "git")
                git init
                ;;
        "npm")
                npm init
                ;;
        "Jean")
                echo "Hé Jean, ça va ?"
                ;;
        "quit")
                break
                ;;
        *)
                echo "J'te connais pas, ouste !"
                ;;
esac
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: You might like to use https://shellcheck.net/ as part of your learning process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read in the input as an array:

```
read -p 'package name ?' -a opts
```

Then loop over the array:

```
for opt in "${opts[@]}"
do
    case "$opt" in
    ...
    esac
done
```

Comment: Yes that's it thank you !